# How do get O365 login status from Registry?

Tags: powershell, office365, registry

I want to get a certain registry key name underneath
`HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities`

As per the screenshot below, I do have two sub-keys, and I like to have the sub-key name for the alphanumeric one with the _ADAL at the end of the name.

Inside this key, there would be a property "SignedOut", when my user is not logged-in to Office365.
This is the information that I need to spit out a message box.

[image]

I was first looking into the MSOline cmdlet, but this will be deprecated in March 2024, so no option anymmore.
GraphAPI will be too complex since I have to register my script to get authentication to the API according to company policy.

Now, we are looking into registry keys, which seem to host the information that I need:

When I exclude the "_AD" at the end of the 2nd key, I get all the ChildItems of my desired key.
My issue is, that the returned "PSCustomObject" contains the name, the properties and also the corresponding values.

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities' -Exclude *_AD`

How can I check whether a "SignedOut" property does exist for this registry key with the alphanumberic name?

Comment: What do you want the script to report if it finds multiple subkeys ending in `_ADAL`?

Comment: From our observations on multiple computers, we only have a single _ADAL.  I assume for the moment that this pattern would be valid with our tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty), and assuming that only *one* key matches `*_ADAL`:

```bash
$prop = 
  Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities\*_ADAL' -Name SignedOut
```

- If the property (registry value) doesn't exist, `$prop` will be `$null`, so you can use `$null -eq $prop` to determine whether it exists.
- If it does exist and you want to extract the property *value* from the `[pscustomobject]` instance returned, use `$prop.SignedOut`

---

If there's a chance that *multiple* keys match and / or you want to know the exact name of the matching *key*(s), you can collect their names and `SignedOut` values in custom objects as follows, using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```bash
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities\*_ADAL' -Name SignedOut | 
  Select-Object @{ n='Identity'; e='PSChildName' }, 
                @{ n='SignedOut'; e={ $_.SignedOut } }
```

Comment: Be careful with the assumption that the path only resolves to one key - it might resolve to multiples, and `if(0){...}` will behave very differently than `if(@(0,0)){...}` :)

Comment: Thanks, @Mathias. Indeed I had assumed that only _one_ key would match. That said, the `$null -eq $prop` test would still work, and `.SignedOut` would result in member-access enumeration, albeit without the ability to know the enclosing key names; I've added another command to address the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the valuable input.  I have it resolved like this:

```
## Check for the availability of the SignedOut property underneath the ..\Identities\*_ADAL registry key  
## and catch the exception when this property does not exist
try { $prop = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities\*_ADAL' -Name SignedOut -ErrorAction Stop }
catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] { $prop = 0 }


if($prop -eq 0) { Write-Host "User is logged-in" }
else {
    Write-Host "User is not logged-in"

    # Determine current user for error message
    $CurrentUser = (Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username.Split('\')[1]

    # Load the PresentationFramework module required for the message box
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

    # Display Messagebox when User is not logged into O365
    # User shall decide whether or not login into Office is desired.

    $msgBoxInput =  [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("You (" + $CurrentUser + ") are currently not authenticated in Office365.`nThis may cause issues in COMOS release workflows.`n`nWould you like to launch Excel to (re-)authenticate?",'Warning: O365 Authentication missing','YesNo','Warning')

    switch  ($msgBoxInput) {

    'Yes' {

        ## We launch Excel; the user shall now authenticate
        $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $Excel.Visible = $true

    }

    'No' {

        ## We do nothing and respect the user decision! 

    }
  }
}
```